# Call function when closing RMI server

Tags: java, rmi, exit, termination

I'm working on a Java RMI application that has many servers. One of these servers is an LDAP-like server that keeps track of the other servers IP addresses (and some other info): Every time a new server is created, it immediately connects to the LDAP-like server which stores its IP by calling the function *connectToLDAP()*:

```
ArrayList<ServerInfo> computingServers = new ArrayList<ServerInfo>();
/**
 * Adds a server to the LDAP to store its IP address
 */
@Override
public void connectToLDAP(int port, int q) throws RemoteException, Exception {
    computingServers.add(new ServerInfo(RemoteServer.getClientHost(), port, q));
}
```

That way, a server only needs to connect to the LDAP-like server to get a list of all the servers IP.

My question is the following: When I run a new server X and it connects to the LDAP-like server, and then I stop the process running X using the Eclipse "Terminate" or using `Ctrl + C` on the terminal, how can the server X call the function below **before quitting** so that the LDAP-like server stays up-to-date?

```
/**
 * Removes a server from the LDAP
 */
@Override
public void removeServer(int port, int q) throws RemoteException, Exception {
    computingServers.remove(new ServerInfo(RemoteServer.getClientHost(), port, q));
}
```

I'm aware it's not the best option but being optimal or following convention is not my focus here. However if there is a completely other way to do what I want, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You could look at a shutdown hook, but they really shouldn't be used for blocking operations.

Comment: But I don't see what use an RMI server's IP address and port number are to anybody., unless they are Registries.

Comment: The IP addresses are used by a single server to connect to all the servers (using IP) at once without having to know them in advance. Port numbers are stored because the network I'm working on only lets me use certain ports, not the default 1099.

Comment: I don't know what a shutdown hook would look like since RMI Threads are not accessible as far as I know?

Comment: What does that have to do with it? You don't need access to RMI threads to install a shutdown hook.

Comment: Sorry, read up more on shutdown hooks and it does work but it is only a partial solution to my problem. The Eclipse "terminate" button forcibly kills a process and therefore a shutdown hook wouldn't work. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: So? The only person who is going to be running this code under Eclipse is you, the developer. Everybody else is gong to be using Ctrl/C, and if you don't like that, provide a proper user interface for closing,

Comment: NB Yours is not a real LDAP server, so the [tag:ldap] tag is totally inappropriate. It actually sound more like a global Registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I added a shutdown hook that sufficed to my needs for this project.